# Surround Text with Tag - PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to do the following in php using regular expressions.

Example string: "the lazy dog barked. Lazy crazy dog."

I want to change it to:

```
"the <tag>lazy</tag> dog barked. <tag>Lazy</tag> crazy dog."
```

So I want to surround every instance of Lazy regardless of case with

I know you can use a regular expression like "/\blazy\b/i" to select for the lazy.

For the life of me can't figure out how to use a preg_replace to substitute the word regardless of case with the same word surrounded by the tags.

Assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Use `'\0'` as a backreference to the match. See [this](http://ideone.com/H5rY5N).

Comment: Look up and try using the function `explode()`. It will separate the whole sentence into separate arrays, and then you can work from there deleting individual words etc.

Comment: @Filip: Explode won't allow whole word search.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_replace_callback in this instance http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php.

```
$string = "the lazy dog barked. Lazy crazy dog.";

$result = preg_replace_callback('/lazy/i', function ($item) {
     return '<tag>' . $item[0] . '</tag>';
}, $string);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

A `preg_replace` with grouping should be able to accomplish this:

```
$string = "the lazy dog barked. Lazy crazy dog.";
echo preg_replace('/\b(lazy)\b/i', '<tag>$1</tag>', $string);
```

Output:

```
the <tag>lazy</tag> dog barked. <tag>Lazy</tag> crazy dog.
```

If you want to replace multiple terms use the or (`|`) between each term.

For example:

```
echo preg_replace('/\b(lazy|tired)\b/i', '<tag>$1</tag>', $string);
```

This will put `lazy` and `tired` inside `tag` elements.

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hT6xR5/1
PHP Demo: https://eval.in/512715